# Atmega328p-pu (arduino bootloader) processor freezes/resets randomly

Tags: arduino, atmega, reset, atmega328p, arduino-uno

I have updated the schematic of my project. The board for this was produced and all components are soldered to the board.

Now I am trying to make a "n20 gear motor" move using the motor driver, I have simplified my code, attached as image(screenshot).

Motor being used: n20 gear motor (produced in china, stalling current should be less than 250mA, normal current is approx 40-50mA.

When I run this code the processor sometimes resets and sometimes freezes completely, this happens frequently but randomly, almost within every minute.
The code itself is pretty simple, I think there is an electrical fault.

Does any of you have an idea what it can be? Thanks in advance.

[image: schematic]

[image: code]

Comment: 2 quick comments: 1) you seem to have some rather current-hungry parts in your circuit, driven off the 5V rail, but in all that, you only have a 1uF main bypass and a few 0.1uF bypasses.  This strikes me as far too few.  I'd throw a 100uF or 1000uF on that 5V rail.  AND: 2) the RST pin concerns me.  You have it tied all the time to +5V (thru the 10k).  So, how will it ever be pulled "low" e.g. at startup?